# How to login Google Play use cookie and Python

Tags: python, http, cookies, urllib2

I want to use python script to login Google Play.And my idea is send a HTTP requset with cookie.

My Python code is like this:

```
import cookielib
import Cookie
import urllib2

def build_opener_with_cookie_str(cookie_str,domain,path='/'):
    simple_cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie(cookie_str);
    cookiejar = cookielib.CookieJar();

    for c in simple_cookie:
        cookie_item = cookielib.Cookie(
            version = 0, name = c, value = str(simple_cookie[c].value),
                        port = None, port_specified = None,
                        domain = domain, domain_specified = None,domain_initial_dot = None,
                        path = path, path_specified = None,
                        secure = None,
                        expires = None,
                        discard = None,
                        comment = None,
                        comment_url = None,
                        rest = None,
                        rfc2109 = False,
            );
        cookiejar.set_cookie(cookie_item);
    return urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar));

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cookie_str = 'My Cookie str look from Chrome Request Headers cookie';
    opener = build_opener_with_cookie_str(cookie_str,domain='https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free');

    html_doc = opener.open('https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free').read();
    print html_doc;
```

But Google Play's response is not a login result.
So what's wrong with my Python code ? Or it was a wrong way use cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I did not look at Google Play for the login but maybe there is for example an hidden field or something similar. You could try to use Beautiful Soup or something similar.

First analyze a normal login with Firebug or similar, where you can see what Google Play will send within a login. If there are hidden fields which are maybe random then try it with Beautiful Soup. But sometimes it is also not functional with Frameworks like Beautiful Soup when Google Play can detect it.

It would be also nice to know what you want to do with your login to maybe give a better answer.